Exists better way to checking error in C?
I'm working with C using the GTK API to create a GUI interface.
What problems will I encounter if I centralize my error checking in my code?
I'm using GError from GLib, and switch case with structs to pick my errors during execution:
    typedef enum
{
    ERROR_NONE,
    ERROR_DUPLICATE_ISBN,
    ERROR_INVALID_INPUT,
    ERROR_INVALID_ISBN
} ErrorCode;

bool check_book_error(CoreWindow *win, const char *title, const char *author, const char *isbn, GError **error)
{   
    //Input check
    if (g_strcmp0(isbn, "") == 0 || g_strcmp0(title, "") == 0 || g_strcmp0(author, "") == 0) {
        g_set_error(error, g_quark_from_static_string("book-error-quark"), ERROR_INVALID_INPUT, "Um ou mais campos estão vazios.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    //ISBN duplicite check
    for (GList *l = win->books; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
        Book *book = l->data;
        if (g_strcmp0(book->isbn, isbn) == 0) {
            g_set_error(error, g_quark_from_static_string("book-error-quark"), ERROR_DUPLICATE_ISBN, "O ISBN '%s' já existe.", isbn);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void handle_book_error(CoreWindow *win, const char  *title, const char *author, const char *isbn)
{
    GError *error = NULL;
    if (!check_book_error(win, title, author, isbn, &error))
    {
        switch (error->code) 
        {
            case ERROR_DUPLICATE_ISBN:
                g_print("Erro: ISBN duplicado. %s\n", error->message);
                break;

            case ERROR_INVALID_INPUT:
                g_print("Erro: Entrada inválida. %s\n", error->message);
                break;
            
            case ERROR_INVALID_ISBN:
                g_print("Erro: ISBN inválido. %s\n", error->message);

            default:
                g_print("Erro desconhecido: %s\n", error->message);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        g_print("Nenhum erro encontrado, continuando operação.\n");
    }
    
}

The function that signal errors to the user is 'handle_book_error'.
From a data security perspective, what are the possible breaches in this case?
For readability and maintainability issues it's good practice, but in other cases is there a better way to manage error checking?
I would like to see different perspectives.
Thanks.
I would just like to see different perspectives, especially from more experienced people.

"I'm using switch case with structs to pick my errors during execution." --> please post your sample code.

Please [edit] your question and add the code (variants) as a [mre] instead of describing the code. With your vague description it is difficult to understand what exactly you want to implement.

Error handling really depend on the context, there's no single "do this" rule, not even for the same program or even source file. Some errors are better handled as close to the problem as possible, while others might just be forwarded up the function call-chain and handled somewhere else.
